# Почему Hibernate игнорирует ON DELETE NO ACTION?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa

В приложении используется `Hibernate`, `Spring DataJPA` и `Spring MVC`. В качестве БД выступает `HSQLDB`.

Имеются сущности Student и Course, связанные отношением ManyToMany:

**Student**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
    List<Course> courses;
    // другие поля
}
```

**Course**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "students_courses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    )
    List<Student> students;
    // другие поля
}
```

**Таблицы**:

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE global_seq PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE courses
(
    id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE global_seq PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE students_courses
(
    student_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    course_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT student_course_idx UNIQUE (student_id, course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES courses (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Вот такой контроллер я использую для студента:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM Student s WHERE s.id=:id")
    int delete(@Param("id") int id);

    // Другие методы опущены
```

---

По задумке нельзя удалять студента, если тот привязан к каким-то курсам. Поэтому я изменил таблицу students_courses:

```
CREATE TABLE students_courses
(
    student_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    course_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT student_course_idx UNIQUE (student_id, course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES courses (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Изменение вот здесь: `FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id)`, я убрал `ON DELETE CASCADE`, чтобы теперь нельзя было удалить студента, который связан с каким-то курсом. Но Hibernate это игнорирует и всё равно удаляет студента, у которого есть связи. Я также попробовал напрямую прописать `ON DELETE NO ACTION`, но это не имеет эффекта - Hibernate всё равно удаляет студента и все записи, связанные с ним.

Любопытно, что, например, `ON DELETE SET NULL` он не игнорирует и выбрасывает ошибку. То есть в принципе он обращает внимание на эту опцию. Почему тогда Hibernate игнорирует `ON DELETE NO ACTION` и что с этим делать?

Comment: Потому что операция удаления выполняется в несколько этапов, в отличие от каскадных операций.

Comment: @RomanC не вполне вас понял. Не могли бы чуть подробней рассказать? И что мне можно сделать в таком случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate вообще никак не смотрит на то, с каким `ON DELETE` создана таблица

Если включите вывод sql запросов в лог, то увидите, что hibernate сначала удаляет записи из связующей таблицы, а затем уже удаляет студентов:

```
Hibernate: delete from students_courses where (student_id) in (select id from students where id=?)
Hibernate: delete from students where id=?
```

Есть посмотреть [исходники](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/exec/DeleteExecutor.java#L35) класса `DeleteExecutor`, то можно увидеть, что при удалении сущности содержащей ManyToMany связь hibernate всегда(без условий) будет удалять строки из связующей таблицы

Добавьте дополнительную проверку перед удаленим студента, например:

```
if (student.courses.size() > 0) {
    throw new CustomException();
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения за долгий ответ... Я просто думал. Да, действительно это так, почему-то в первую очередь удаляются записи из таблицы связей. Тут, видимо, без проверки не обойтись.